# Using substr and instr to update a delimited string

Tags: sql, oracle, decode, substr

I have the following data in a column named `datos`. I want to update the text after the 8th slash (DR004), to be DR013.

```
/1/14/0/0/ / / /DR004/1/rttrgftgr/ZM003/0/0/0/1/0/
```

I have tried using this

```
update sumcon
  set substr(datos, instr(datos, '/', 1, 8) + 1, 1) = 
        decode(substr(datos, instr(datos, '/', 1, 8) + 1, 1), ' ', 'DR013') 
  where nis_rad = 200000732;
```

but it's not working.

Here is a sample of the data from `datos` column

```
/1/14/0/0/ / / / /1/ / /0/0/0/1/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / /DR008/1/ /ZM004/0/0/0/0/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / / /1/ / /0/0/0/1/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / / /1/ / /0/0/0/1/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / / /1/ / /0/0/0/1/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / / /1/ / /0/1/0/0/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / /DR008/1/ /ZM004/0/0/0/1/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / / /1/ / /0/0/1/1/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / / /1/ / /0/0/0/1/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / / /1/ / /0/0/0/1/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / / /1/ / /0/0/0/1/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / /DR001/1/ /ZM004/0/0/0/0/0/
/1/14/0/0/ / / / /1/ / /0/0/0/1/0/
```

Comment: so you guys just edit the quiz instead? somehow

Comment: Is it always true that there will be a 9th slash immediately after the value `DR004`?

Comment: Then the easiest way is to extract substr from 1 to 8th slash, append the static value to it, and then append the substr from 9th slash till end.

Comment: Bob has already posted what I suggested :-)

Comment: Are you sure DR004 will occur only once? If it occurs only once, then you could simply replace it. My answer will depend on your confirmation.

Comment: it does not occur once, infact in most cases cases it is i am updating a space...  see paste from my database in answer below

Comment: Ok, got it. But, delete your post as an answer. Edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [@LalitKumarB's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3989608/lalit-kumar-b) suggestion, change your UPDATE statement to

```
UPDATE SUMCON
  SET DATOS = SUBSTR(DATOS, 1, INSTR(DATOS, '/', 1, 8)) ||
              'DR013' ||
              SUBSTR(DATOS, INSTR(DATOS, '/', 1, 9))
  WHERE NIS_RAD = 200000732;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4cf40/5)

Comment: Yeah, this is what I suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression:

```
UPDATE sumcon
SET    datos   = REGEXP_REPLACE( datos, '(/(.*?/){7}).*?/', '\1' || :new_value || '/' )
WHERE  nis_rad = 200000732;
```

- `(/(.*?/){7})` - will find the first `/` then will match zero-or-more of any characters `.*?` until another `/` is found and then repeat this match 7 times (to get the first slash and then 7 successive one) - this will all be stored in a capturing group (denoted by the surrounding `()`s).
- `.*?/` will match zero-or-more of any characters `.*?` until another `/` is found - this is what you want to replace.

Comment: +1 and agreed that this is a nice solution; however, OP specifically requested a solution using SUBSTR and INSTR.

Comment: MT0, yes your solution works as well as Bob Jarvis' one..Thank you guys..i owe you one

Comment: It's like shooting birds with a canon. Why regexp for such trivial requirement. Also, regexp are CPU intensive and still not faster than the good old substr + instr approach.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - on one hand I agree that using a regular expression search for a relatively simple requirement is overkill. On the other hand, regular expressions are a good tool to be familiar with. Gripping hand, they require practice to be used well - thus, practicing with simple problems is a viable option. :-)

Comment: For practise? Yes, sure. Why not, I completely agree. We are fortunate enough to work in IT industry to have test environments ;-) Anyway, I am not at all against the use of REGEX, in fact I have had used different flavours of regex. I was so happy the day I explored the shortest way to split a comma delimited string using regex :-) My only intention was to point out the performance aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if it working.

You can do this something similar to

```
update sumcon
set datos = substr(datos, 1, instr(datos, '/', 1, 7) ||
            :new_value ||
            substr(datos, instr(datos, '/', 1, 8)
where nis_rad = 200000732;
```

But generally you should not do that. Instead you should to redesign your table and divide the `datos` field to many atomic fields.

Comment: Sanders, i will not redesign my table as the value is being updated and inserted  by several  programs